# pg_restore and psql asks password for restoring dump file

Tags: postgresql, restore, dump

This will be probably extreme novice question but I want to restore a .backup dump file. I have tried the following command:

```
pg_restore -i -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d old_db -v C:/blabla/bla.backup
```

First error I have encountered because the dump file is in text format so I should restore it using psql.

Then I have tried this command:

```
psql dbname < C:/blabla/bla.backup
```

But didn't accept the password of my windows user password

Comment: Do you have a database user?  One of the differences between the two commands is `-U postgres`

Comment: yes I have just one db user "postgres" but the second command does not accept the password of the windows user. It is in german but something like authentication for the user "mtuna" was not succesful

Comment: psql dbname postgres < C:/blabla/bla.backup solved the problem thanks